# Why can't I pass an anonymous function to dplyr's filter without getting errors about vector size?

Tags: r, dplyr, anonymous-function

Coming from base R, I expected the following to work as a way to pass anonymous functions

```
library(tidyverse)
starwars %>%
  select(height) %>% 
  filter(function(x) x > 100)
```

It does not. It reports the following:

```
Error in `filter()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = function(x) x > 100`.
Caused by error in `vec_size()`:
! `x` must be a vector, not a function.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I suspect that I'm making a fundamental error, but I see no comparable examples in the documentation. Where is my misunderstanding of how dplyr handles such cases?

Comment: I might easily be mistaken, but I don't think I've seen any examples of using a function as a (solitary) argument to `dplyr::filter`; note that `dplyr::filter` is very different from `base::Filter`, where a function is required. Have you looked into `dplyr::if_any` and related functions?

Comment: For instance, `... %>% filter(if_any(everything(), function(x) x > 100))`?

Comment: What you're trying to do here is essentially `starwars["height"][function(x) x > 100,]` in base R. Which doesn't work there either. `filter()` requires a logical TRUE/FALSE selection. I gather you just want `starwars %>% filter(height > 100)`

Comment: what about explicitly defining the function, then apply it with clear argument? ```f = function(x) x > 100; starwars %>%
    select(height) %>% 
    filter(f(height))```

Comment: The `...` argument to `dplyr::filter()` has to be an expression of the `data.frame` passed to it `.data` per the [docs](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter.html): "Expressions that return a logical value, and are defined in terms of the variables in .data.". That's not the case of the function you passed but is the case for `dplyr::if_any` as suggested by r2evans. To add to thelatemail comment: `starwars %>% filter(.data$height > 100)` and `starwars %>% filter(.data[["height"]] > 100)` also work.